# Is there a way to get list of labels from a custom classifier on AWS Comprehend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, classification, amazon-comprehend, aws-sdk-comprehend

I have trained a custom classifier for AWS Comprehend to identify what kind of document an input is, whether it's an invoice or a medical form, or some kind of tax form. Now that I have my model, I am looking to use it, but I also want to provide a list of possible classifier labels that my model is capable of outputting.

So far, I've looked in the documentation for Comprehend, like here: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/comprehend/index.html#cli-aws-comprehend

But I've yet to find anything that fits what I'm looking for. The only way that I think might work is to use `list-document-classifiers`, get my model, and then access the S3 bucket (using the `S3Uri`) for the training data and try and get a list from the data itself, but that's really inefficient.